# How to delete a Whatsapp group without admin privileges

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Today, I have created a Whatsapp group and accidentally left the group. Now the present admin of the group is not able to add me back. Kindly suggest me what to do.

Comment: well why is he not able to add you? Any error message?

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete a WhatsApp group unless you're the last person leaving it. If your friend's phone is throwing an error, try getting him to make another member of the group an admin, and then the second admin could try adding you. But deleting the group without it being completely devoid of members is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

As the Admins, you could delete the group. Unfortunately, Whatsapp admins. have recently eliminated that option, and without notice.

I see NO rational in the absence of this feature. If you created a group, you should have that same power to delete the group.